# How make useEffect work with chaining async/wait map?

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I'm making an API call and then afterwards there is a chaining async/await.

When the page loads, the code is not executing the chaining part, I'm getting just the `arrayDrivers`.

**How can I make the useEffect perform the chaining async/wait when the page loads?**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import DriversList from "../components/DriversList";
import axios from "axios";

const GetDrivers = () => {
  const [drivers, setDrivers] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchDriver = async () => {
      const res1 = await axios.get("http://ergast.com/api/f1/2022/drivers.json?limit=25");
      const arrayDrivers = res1.data.MRData.DriverTable.Drivers;
      setDrivers(arrayDrivers);
      await Promise.all(
        drivers.map(async (driver) => {
          const searchTitle = `/api.php?action=query&generator=search&format=json&gsrsearch=${driver.givenName}_${driver.familyName}&gsrlimit=1&prop=info`;
          const res2 = await axios.get(searchTitle);
          const driverTitle = Object.values(res2.data.query.pages)[0].title;
          const linkPhoto = `/api.php?action=query&titles=${driverTitle}&prop=pageimages&format=json&pithumbsize=400`;
          const res3 = await axios.get(linkPhoto);
          const thumbSource = Object.values(res3.data.query.pages)[0].thumbnail.source;
          driver.photo = thumbSource;
          console.log(driver);
        }, setIsLoading(false))
      );
    };
    fetchDriver();
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);
  return <>{isLoading ? <p>Loading...</p> : <DriversList drivers={drivers} />}</>;
};

export default GetDrivers;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're updating state *before* you've finished modifying your data:

```
setDrivers(arrayDrivers);
await Promise.all(
  //...
);
```

Modify the data, *then* use that data to update state:

```
await Promise.all(
  //...
);
setDrivers(arrayDrivers);
```

---

Additionally, you're not modifying the actual data.  You're trying to modify *the empty array from state*:

```
drivers.map(async (driver) => {
```

The data you got from the server is in `arrayDrivers`:

```
arrayDrivers.map(async (driver) => {
```

Comment: I edited my code as you said but still the `console.log(driver);` is not running as expected.

Comment: @guilhermxlopes: I've updated the answer.  You were also iterating over the wrong array, so there was nothing to `.map()`.

Comment: I feeling like an idiot, thank you for your time.